# Build and assign Lambda expression iteratively

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Consider the following:

```
var Constraints = new NonlinearConstraint[2*nVars];

var Constraints = new[] {
    new NonlinearConstraint(nVars, x => x[0] >= 0),
    new NonlinearConstraint(nVars, x => x[0] <= 1),
    new NonlinearConstraint(nVars, x => x[1] >= 0),
    new NonlinearConstraint(nVars, x => x[1] <= 1),
}; 
// et cetera for all x[i]
```

I am tring to find a way to construct this variable using a for loop for all `x[i]`;

I am unable to find any proper documentation on this. I have tried using

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<>();
```

However I run into a conversion error code

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the code you were trying to use that you got the error?..

Comment: That error is: `Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'` - No way to help besides seeing code

Comment: Please be more specific, is using a `List` a solution for you or are you avoiding to write the lines manually, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Enumerable.Range(0, nVars)
          .SelectMany(i => new[]
                           {
                               new NonlinearConstraint(nVars, x => x[i] >= 0),
                               new NonlinearConstraint(nVars, x => x[i] <= 1),
                           })
          .ToArray();
```

This creates an array of `NonlinearConstraint`s, two for each `i` from `0` to `nVars-1`...

That is, you don't create the *lambda* iteratively, but the *array of constraint objects*. Each of those has its own lambda, of course...

Comment: Could you please explain `var localI = i`, why not use `i` instead?

Comment: The lambdas use the value of the captured variables when they are executed, that is, if you use `i` directly, all constraints will adress the last variable. Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=modified+closure

Comment: While it is true that closures capture (variables) by reference in C#, this is not relevant in your case. `i` is not a local variable but the parameter of the lambda (which implies that there is no need to capture it). Proof: `Enumerable.Range(0, 10).SelectMany(i => new[] { i }).First()` is 0 (should be 10 if your claim was correct).